# PromQL - Multiple time range exclusion

Tags: promql, victoriametrics

in query_range is possible to specify a start and end date.
Is it possible to specify time range exclusions within start/end time range?
For example:

start=2020-12-19T00:00:00.000Z
end=2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z

and excluding period

exclusion_start=2020-12-21T00:00:00.000Z
exclusion_end=2020-12-21T23:00:00.000Z

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: it is not possible, use separate queries instead.

The /query_range endpoint was initially designed for plotting time series in systems like Grafana. And for this case range exclusion doesn't really needed, in my opinion. But you always can issue multiple queries divided by time range as you need.

Comment: It is possible to exclude time ranges via a hacky approach based on time-related [functions](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/) such as `time()`, `hour()`, `day_of_month()`, etc. See https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6592#issuecomment-389119647